# RabbitMQ - Do not deliver mesage until last one is Acked

Tags: rabbitmq

I am planning to implement a message broker for our system and mostly have decided on RabbitMQ. However, I needed to know it such a thing is possible using RabbitMQ.

**Procuder produces 2 messages for Object O

1) A (create an O object),

B (update the same O object).**

**On the consumer side(multiple consumers) that is registered to the queue to get messages for object O, I want B to be delivered only after A is Acked.**

**Goal - So that the Create is processed for Object O and then the Update is processed for that same object.**

Answer (score 0):

What you're wanting to do is guarantee delivery and consumer processing order, plus only process one at a time. This is only possible under certain conditions. Even then, it tends to create strange problem areas.

The conditions that have to be met:

1. messages must have some kind of header entry to know what order they are supposed to be processed in
2. you can only have 1 consumer for the queue in which these messages will live
3. that consumer must [set prefetch to 1](https://www.rabbitmq.com/consumer-prefetch.html)
4. The consumer is set to auto_ack false (require ack)
5. when (not if) an out of order message is pulled from the queue, you must handle it

the problem with doing this, is that you will never be guaranteed that messages arrive in rabbitmq from the producer in the right order. network hiccups, latency and other problems will occur. therefore, you will at sometime end up with message 2 sitting in the queue before message 1 gets there.

beyond that, when it comes time to consume a message, you will have to be able to handle this scenario where messages are out of order. typically this is done by holding on to the message and pulling the next one from the queue until you get the right one. sort the messages that yuo're holding onto and then you can process them in order

to guarantee this works on the consumer side of things, there can be only one consumer for the queue and that consumer must have a prefetch of 1, as noted above. this will cause the consumer to pull only 1 message at a time.

in this setup, you will only ever be able to have 1 consumer for this queue. you will never be able to scale out with more consumers on this queue.

you should note that the constraints here are not due to rabbitmq, but are constraints found in any distributed system.

Comment: what's your preferred approach to this sort of problem (handling message ordering, idempotency when materializing a view of data from domain events)? Do you know of a way to sidestep the problem altogether? Certainly it is important for a materialized view to e.g a createEvent to be processed before a deleteEvent. Is event sourcing the only answer here?